# Displaying different language with db on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode, utf-8

I tried to display data from a form (ASP.NET using C#). However, When the data passed it shown it on the table as: `?????` instead of the real value.

I tried to unicode my project to utf-8 by add this to the `webconfig file`:

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
  </system.web>
```

However, it still didn't works. I tried to display a data that contains hebrew languague if it matters. I wonder if I should define something on my db also (If yes, I am using Visual Studio), as I always did it on PHP. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Textboxes will not display unicode so you need to use RichTextBox instead.  Neither will a console window.  You did not specify what you were using to display the unicode text.

Comment: Sorry. I used a text-box element, and on the server side, just displayed them by xx.Text;

Comment: So what should I do instead of this?

Comment: A RichTextBox..

Comment: I didn't think it is the best solution. I just need to display user's first and last name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display text using the unicode table you will need to use A RichTextbox instead of a normal textbox because RichTextBox support much more option like you can see in the documentation for the control :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

you can change for example :

- font size
- font style
- Use Different Language ( What you were searching for )

Comment: I didn't think it is the best solution. I just need to display user's first and last name.